# How to make my visual studio solution use the latest version of nuget.exe in teamcity

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, teamcity

I have a .net website written some years ago which causes an error when being built in TeamCity. when teamcity gets to the second build step, MSBuild of the site's csproj file, i get this error when it tries to run package restore:
"The '…' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.60318.667'"
The reason for this is that this solution includes the nuget.exe file in its directory which is of version 2.8.60318.667. Other projects/websites that i work on do not have the nuget.exe file in them and seem to be building in teamcity okay.

I need to either (1) update the solution so that i can remove the nuget.exe file, or (2) use the latest version, which should hopefully fix the teamcity issue.

When i replace my nuget.exe file with the latest from nuget i get an error message on build:
"1>D:\Sites\testSite.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Sites\testSite\ \packages\System.Security.AccessControl.4.4.0'."
I think there is a space somewhere in a configuration file between the solution directory and the package location but i'm not sure where to look. Can anyone help?

I have tried deleting the .nuget folder from my solution but i get errors when i build. Can anyone help me reconfigure my solution to work without the specific, local version of nuget?

If anyone can help in any way i'd really appreciate it, i'm reaching the limit of my understanding of visual studio and .net.

thanks

Sam

Comment: No need to change in solution file. You can do it form TeamCity  as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had when replacing the nuget.exe file was due to the version of the file I downloaded. I took an older version (4.6.4) and I did not get the issue with the space in the path to the packages when building the solution.

There were other errors but i have resolved them now.

Answer (score 1):

You can install multiple versions of Nuget tool in TeamCity and set any one as default

**i.e** v4.4 as default.

For this follow the TeamCity doc link : [TeamCity Doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/nuget.html#NuGet-InstallingNuGettoTeamCityagents)

Now for **specific build step** if you want to use lower version of nuget you can **choose different version of nuget installer/restore** as shown in attached image

[image]

Comment: thanks Niraj, unfortunately i don't have this build step set up. It seems that when package restore is triggered by the solution build it is using the version of nuget that is included in the project root. I think this setup is incorrect but i have resolved it by updating the nuget.exe file. I'll bear this in mind in the future, i think it would be better to run it the way you have shown.